# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' for BlogPost and Groups

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Moin moin...
i have a big problem with an INSERT in my contentcollection table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contentcollections` (
`collection_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`author_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`description` longtext,
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`picture` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`collection_id`),
KEY `is_active` (`is_active`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

All references are stored here. Then there are the tables:

contents - for BlogPost

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contents` (
`content_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`author_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`body` longtext NOT NULL,
`allow_comments` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`collection_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`trackbacks` text,
`display_on` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`is_html` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`content_id`),
KEY `homepage_content` (`is_active`,`display_on`,`collection_id`,`created`),
KEY `homepage_typed_content` (`is_active`,`display_on`,`collection_id`,`type`,`created`),
KEY `user_content` (`is_active`,`collection_id`,`author_id`,`created`),
KEY `user_typed_content` (`is_active`,`collection_id`,`author_id`,`type`,`created`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and groups

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
`group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`access_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reg_type` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_moderated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`header_image` text,
`header_image_action` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`display_header_image` varchar(40) DEFAULT '1',
`extra` text,
`group_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'regular',
PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now i can write blog posts, so many I want. The reference is stored with collection_id 1 in contentcollections. The BlogPost becomes a content_id 1, 2, 3 and so on. But if I want to insert a group:

> INSERT INTO `c1CN`.`contentcollections` (collection_id, author_id, type, title, description, is_active, created, changed, picture) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Cyberspace-Networks', '', 1, 1451321062, 1451321062, '') [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY']

The same if I start with groups. The reference is stored. The Groups becomes a group_id. But if I want to insert a BlogPost comes the same error message...

This is the insert code:

```
        //If exists then update else insert
    if ($this->collection_id) {
        $sql = "UPDATE {contentcollections} SET type = ?, author_id = ?, title = ?, description = ?, changed =?, picture = ? WHERE collection_id = ?";
        $data = array($this->type, $this->author_id, $this->title, $this->description, time(), $this->picture, $this->collection_id);
        $res = Dal::query($sql, $data);
    } else {
        // get id
        $this->collection_id = Dal::next_id("ContentCollection");
        $this->created = time();
        $this->changed = time();
        $this->is_active = 1;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {contentcollections} (collection_id, author_id, type, title, description, is_active, created, changed, picture) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $data = array($this->collection_id, $this->author_id, $this->type, $this->title, $this->description, $this->is_active, $this->created, $this->changed, $this->picture);
        $res = Dal::query($sql, $data);
    }
    Logger::log("Exit: ContentCollection::save()");
    return;
}
```

Has anyone here an idea?

This is the code to store a group:

```
/**
* Saves Group data to database
* @access public
* @param int $user_id ID of the user trying to save
*/
public function save ($user_id=NULL) {
 Logger::log('Enter: Group::save() | Args: \$user_id = '.$user_id);
 if (!empty($user_id)) {
   $this->author_id = $user_id;
 }

 if (empty($this->title)) {
  Logger::log('Exit: Group::save(). Title of the group is not specified.');
  throw new CNException(GROUP_NAME_NOT_EXIST, 'Title of the group is not specified');
 }
 if (!isset($this->access_type)) {
  Logger::log('Exit: Group::save(). Access type for the group is not specifed');
  throw new CNException(GROUP_ACCESS_TYPE_NOT_EXIST, 'Access type for the group is not specifed');
 }
 if (!isset($this->reg_type)) {
  Logger::log('Exit: Group::save(). User registration type is not specified for the group.');
  throw new CNException(GROUP_REGISTRATION_TYPE_NOT_EXIST, 'User registration type is not specified for the group.');
 }
 if (!isset($this->is_moderated)) {
  Logger::log('Exit: Group::save(). Moderation type is not specifed for the group.');
  throw new CNException(GROUP_IS_MODERATED_NOT_EXIST, 'Moderation type is not specifed for the group.');
 }

 if (!empty($this->extra)) {
    $this->extra = serialize($this->extra);
 }

 //if collection_id exists the update else insert
 if ($this->collection_id) {

 //       $user_type = Group::get_user_type ($this->author_id, $this->collection_id);
//       $access = $this->acl_object->acl_check( 'action', 'edit', 'users', $user_type, 'group', 'all' );
   $access = PermissionsHandler::can_group_user(Group::get_owner_id((int)$this->collection_id), $this->collection_id, array('permissions' => 'manage_groups'));

   if (!$access) {

     throw new CNException(OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED, 'You are not authorized to edit this group.');
   }

   $sql = "UPDATE {groups} SET access_type = ?, reg_type = ?, is_moderated = ?, category_id = ? , header_image = ? , header_image_action = ?, display_header_image = ?, group_type =?, extra=? WHERE group_id = ?";
   try {
     $res = Dal::query($sql, array($this->access_type, $this->reg_type, $this->is_moderated, $this->category_id, $this->header_image, $this->header_image_action, $this->display_header_image, $this->group_type, $this->extra, $this->collection_id));
     parent::save();
   } catch (Exception $e) {
     Dal::rollback();
     throw $e;
   }
 }
 else {
   //only registered user can create a group
   // This already has been taken care via session
   // we can add further modification if not use session user_id

   try {
     parent::save();
     $sql = "INSERT INTO {groups} (group_id, access_type, reg_type, is_moderated, category_id, header_image, header_image_action, display_header_image, group_type, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?, ?, ?)";
     $data = array($this->collection_id, $this->access_type, $this->reg_type, $this->is_moderated,$this->category_id,$this->header_image,$this->header_image_action,$this->display_header_image, $this->group_type, $this->extra);
     $res = Dal::query($sql, $data);

     $this->created = time();

     $sql = "INSERT INTO {groups_users} (group_id, user_id, user_type, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
     $res = Dal::query($sql, array($this->collection_id, $this->author_id, OWNER, $this->created));

     foreach ($this->moderators as $mod) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO {groups_users} (group_id, user_id, user_type, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
       $res = Dal::query($sql, array($this->collection_id, $mod, MODERATOR, $this->created));
     }
     Dal::commit();

    // setup extra permissions for group owner
     // so, we need to assign group admin role to group owner now:
     $role_extra = array( 'user' => false, 'network' => false, 'groups' => array($this->collection_id) );
     $user_roles[] = array('role_id' => GROUP_ADMIN_ROLE, 'extra' => serialize($role_extra));
     $group_owner = new User();
     $group_owner->load($this->author_id);
     $group_owner->set_user_role($user_roles);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
     Dal::rollback();
     throw $e;
   }
 }

 Logger::log("Exit: Group::save()");
 return $this->collection_id;
 }
```

Comment: When you say "if I want to insert a group" the INSERT COMMAND that appears just next makes an insert into contentcollections not into groups table.

Comment: Yes... in contentcollections...